# Anylogic unable to open .alp extension

Tags: anylogic

I've been working on Anylogic and it was really good unless 3 days ago something happened and I don't know why. So I created one model and it was working well after I placed parameters in the Main agent something goes wrong.

I saved it and then I try to open this model but it says 'unable to open the model' and ' invalid project file format'. What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted file, did you force-close AnyLogic or store the model in Dropbox, GDrive or OneDrive or similar?

Comment: it might be force-close I guess and support says that there is a backup file .alp.bak but I couldn't find it because I'm using macOS. so i don't know how can i find it

Comment: Should be in the same model folder... Always make sure you have backups yourself, though. Best use GitHub or some other versioning tool.

Comment: Try opening the file with a text editor - maybe internally it is JSON/XML etc. Also do some research to see if it is a zip file, as some Microsoft Office files now are.